# Django management command cannot see arguments?

Tags: django, django-1.8

Since upgrading to Django 1.8, there's a strange bug in my Django management command.

I run it as follows:

```
python manage.py my_command $DB_NAME $DB_USER $DB_PASS
```

And then I collect the arguments as follows:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    print args
    db_name = args[0]
    db_user = args[1]
    db_pass = args[2]
    self.conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db_name, user=db_user,
                                 password=db_pass)
```

Previously this worked fine, but now I see this error:

```
usage: manage.py my_command [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                                             [--settings SETTINGS]
                                             [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                                             [--traceback] [--no-color]
manage.py my_command: error: unrecognized arguments: test test test
```

It's not even getting as far as the `print args` statement.

If I run it without any arguments, then it errors on the `args[0]` line, unsurprisingly.

Am I using `args` wrong here? Or is something else going on?

Comment: Is this a real case scenario? There is already `dbshell` in Django. You're reinventing the wheel. You can call the DB command line with `python manage.py dbshell`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a change in Django 1.8. As detailed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#management-commands-that-only-accept-positional-arguments):

> #### Management commands that only accept positional arguments
>
> If you have written a custom management command that only accepts positional arguments and you didn’t specify the **args** command variable, you might get an error like **Error: unrecognized arguments: ...**, as variable parsing is now based on **argparse** which doesn’t implicitly accept positional arguments. You can make your command backwards compatible by simply setting the **args** class variable. However, if you don’t have to keep compatibility with older Django versions, it’s better to implement the new **add_arguments()** method as described in Writing custom django-admin commands.

Answer (score 5):

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('args', nargs='*')
```

Add the above for compatibility, breaking it was a really unwise decision from the folks updating the django.

Comment: This is the right way to specify the arguments. However I don't agree that it was really unwise. Sometimes you have to break with the past and move forward.